# Дайте совет жизненный, куда двигаться в Java направлении

Tags: java, работа

Хех, молодость быстро пролетела, аж не верится.

Вопрос не нубский, много чего прочитано, в общем так:
Почти под 30, непрофильное ВО, мозг не поплавился, руки относительно прямые, настроение бодрое. По трудовой и в офисе никогда не работал, на вольных хлебах. Последние 7 лет занимался контекстной рекламой, дорвеями, но постепенно эта сфера накрылась. На хлеб вполне хватало. Но сейчас речь не об этом. Нет дохода, короче... Писать статьи, копирайтить - можно, но не вариант.

Программирование реально интересовало еще с младенчества, в 6 лет бейсик учил, потом забросил. Короче, принципы основные еще в детстве понял, но опыта нет.

Сейчас надо в программинг влиться.

Из знаний имеется следующее: html, css, wordpress, достаточно средние знания php.
Было также обнаружено, что наиболее востребованным и высокооплачиваемым языком является Java Прочитан Шилдт - не только прочитан, а никаких проблем с пониманием ООП, синтаксиса и пр. Сейчас читается Эккель. Тоже все понятно. С теорией проблем нет.

Вероятно, сейчас та стадия, когда можно на джуниора идти. Но есть две проблемы: возраст уже не тот + живу в городишке, где 0 it-контор. Тут семья, ребенок, короче, надо фрилансить.

Впереди полгода свободного времени (фин.подушка).

Подскажите, в каком направлении в Java развиваться. Вопрос не в том, что интересует или не интересует, вопрос в том, как можно на этом делать деньги 100% на фрилансе или на удаленке с прицелом на odesk, elance.

Есть пару вариантов:

- долбить верстку, php, но уж больно смущает дикий демпинг со стороны pakistan-india, да и рейты невысокие.
- долбить Java, что, собственно, и происходит, но куда дальше двигаться? Java, судя по всему, язык в основном офисного, корпоративного характера. Можно android разработку учить, но снова-таки мутновато, ибо жить чисто за счет дохода с приложений не совсем ясно как.

Короче, есть high motivation, неплохой english, ну и, наверное, джуниорские познания в Джаве, хотя без практики, которые совершенствуются ежедневно, ибо 10 часов в день познаю новое. Чего дальше делать? Набить практики? Да, это можно - задачки с и-нета прочитать, еще мануал какой-нибудь освоить.

Я читал подобные топики, но люди в основном спрашивают с нуля, у меня же вопрос конкретный: как Java во фрилансе применить-то, что конкретно учить? Складывается впечатление, что Java и фриланс - вещи несовместимые.

Есть варианты экзотики какой-нибудь заняться типа RoR, Python, но распыляться неохота. Java - так Java, тем более, что хорошо пошла.

Подскажете чего-нибудь?

P.S. Срываться с семьей в МСК, проситься на джуна - уж очень крайний вариант.

Comment: Подобный вопрос на Java толках : http://javatalks.ru/topics/35114

Comment: Я бы не советовал по новому учить язык, уже можно себе просто дальше верстать сайтики и не переживать.

Comment: 2 vkovalchuk88: Сколько наблюдаю за людьми, то все больше поражаюсь факту "Энергичный человек - успешный человек". На самом деле, чем больше изучаешь, тем лучше, если конечно изучаемое применяется на практике. Все потому что появляется возможность посмотреть на решаемые проблемы под разными точками зрения. К примеру у меня появилось лучшие навыки работы с командной строкой Windows, после того как поработал дома на FreeBSD в качестве основной системы и стал лучше проектировать интерфейс консольных утилит. Надо только четко знать, а что ты хочешь? Вот об этом автор и спрашивает, чтобы знать это

Comment: больше всего меня тут радуют 12и летние советчики =(

Comment: Ну если честно, с высоты 10-летнего опыта работы в ИТ-сфере скажу, что и в 12-летнем "смысле" тоже есть смысл. Как правило нам "опытным" иногда замуссоливает глаза наш опыт и вместо того чтобы что-то попробовать и сказать мнение на основе действительных фактов после экспериментов. Мы "опытные" достаточно часто ставим себе какие-то абсурдные рамки

Comment: @sys_dev,  ну можно двигаться в одном направлении а не по новому все начинать. У него же есть базовые навики html сss. Там есть тоже куда развиваться в вэб. А если вы системный программист то конечно FreeBSD покопать будет полезно.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88: А от любого программиста не ждут, что он сядет и напишет драйвер для Linux, хотя он всю жизнь писал GUI на Objective-C. Но на него посмотрят как на дебила, если он поставить Linux не сможет! Ведь что по сути требуется от любого ИТ-специалиста? Умение работать с документацией! Умение решать проблемы, за хоть какой-то обозримый срок. Другими словами, если я никогда не писал драйверов под OS X, то я прямо скажу "Я напишу, но это займет длительное время и больших финансовых вложений. Оно вам надо?". Именно этого и ждут от ИТ-специалиста! Прогнозируемости!

Comment: @sys_dev, это правда.

Comment: RE: Сейчас надо в программинг влиться. Можно попробовать ходит на какие-нибудь курсы, прежде чем вливаться в программинг.

Comment: Читать  [куда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864480/204920) развиваться.

Answer (score 5):

Не слушай никого - тридцатник абсолютно нормальный возраст, чтобы влиться в программинг. Я входил в программинг 3 раза: каждый раз с перерывом в 10 лет. В последний раз в 40 лет и вполне успешно. Ну это отдельная тема.

Проблема с Java состоит в том, что она востребована в энтерпрайзе, а энтерпрайз живет в мегаполисах - в малых городах с Java ловить нечего.

Я бы все таки двинулся в сторону ближайшего мегаполиса: написал труднопроверяемый CV (все равно это читают только HR'ы, а тим лидов интересует как ты пишешь) и начал с джуниора. В свое время со своим соракетом я сидел в джуниорах ровно 3 месяца, потом быстро двинулся по лесенке. А еще через полгода я уже сам выбирал.

В моем понимании во фрилансе жизни нет - я в это не верю. Работал конечно сам с фрилансом, но как то веры никогда не было.

Comment: я же писал, что есть исключения из того, что я написал. буду рад если автор темы попадете в этот исключительный случай.

Comment: @Barmaley оно, конечно, sorry & offtopic, но

      Я входил в программинг 3 раза: каждый раз с перерывом в 10 лет

чем-то мне напоминает:

      Бросить курить легко. Я сам сто раз бросал.

Comment: @alexlz так оно и есть :) Проблема с программингом в том, что с одной стороны мне нравится кодить, с другой стороны за кодирование платят хуже чем за некодирование (у меня есть еще и другая специализация). Вот так все и происходит: только начнешь по человечески кодировать и тебе раз по голове и предлагают в 2-3 раза выше чем за кодирование - приходится уходить. А тоска по кодированию остается...

Comment: Если нет жизни в фрилансе - то где она есть?

Comment: @Barmaley а в какой момент произошел тот переломный момент, что вы поняли => ```А еще через полгода я уже сам выбирал```  , какое качество вы считаете наиболее важным для программиста ? //ну то есть условно для сравнения => не зрячий не сможет стричь к примеру 
  //  [мне самой интересно как именно к этому пути придти правильно, что именно делать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12083/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1):

Начинать учиться программированию в за 30 не вижу смысла но бывают исключения.

Можете начать с фриланса. По опыту работы последних пол года могу сказать, что 95% всех проектов написано на php. Писать практически с нуля ничего не нужно. Обычно это всякие более менее популярные CMS типа Bitrix. Бывают проекты которые нужно поддерживать за копейки но это в основной массе быдло код. Остальные 5% это python, java и т.д.. Встречаются проекты на java но так просто по участвовать не получится так как заказчикам интересен выполненные уже проекты т.е. портфолио. Также не ждите от фриланса денег. Как правило платят очень мало. Очень большая вероятность вообще остаться без денег (если работаете без предоплаты) если по каким то причинам проект заказчику стал не интересен. По предоплате с вами без портфолио тоже работать не будут. Для опыта можно поучаствовать за символическую плату т.е. бесплатно -). Переезжать в Москву без конкретного опыта в программировании и без участия в реальных проектах я бы не советовал но тут опять же есть исключения. Если вас соблазняют зарплаты для java разработчиков на HH.ru то смею вас заверить в большинстве случаев это лож не считая очень крупные и известные компании но я думаю вас там даже рассматривать не будут если у вас нет там своего инсайдера.

Могу еще много интересного рассказать но это уже в личку.

Comment: в свете вот таких новостей http://habrahabr.ru/post/199024/ я думаю стоит призадуматься а стоит ли вообще начинать свою карьеру в ИТ. Скоро в ИТ будут зп как у дворников и продавцов на рынках

Comment: > Если вас соблазняют зарплаты для java разработчиков на HH.ru то смею вас заверить в большинстве случаев это лож

Не стоит драматизировать. Открытых вакансий тьма, а стоящих разработчиков - единицы. FizzBuzz и бинарный поиск способен написать лишь каждый пятый собеседумый. Компании месяцами не могут найти заполнить вакансии.

Comment: @huffman, в моем городе средняя зарплата php-программистов 30к - такая же зарплата у водителя автобуса и строителя. Я не php-программист, но их у нас большинство.

Comment: коллеги, я совершенно не драматизирую, я коротко изложил ту ситуацию которая есть на самом деле в мск. Что касается алгаритмов сортировки, поиска и т.д, так я не встречал еще пэхэпэ программистов которые бы про это даже слышали. Прочтение книг по данным тематикам тоже не гарантирует того, что читающий понял суть и сможет применять на практике полученные знания. Все это приходит только с многолетним опытом. Но опять же есть исключения. Если вы гений, вперед. Но где вы были раньше? -)

Comment: В основном все претензии к PHP потому что он самый популярный :-) Ну я прав же, и постоянно есть работа у PHP спецов. 
Или что аргументы в разном порядке по историческим причинам стоят:-) Ничем этот python не лучше, разве что он развивается вроде. А в остальном все верно

Comment: @huffman: Да ну? Изложил все как на самом деле? Нет! Даже если и понаберут "Дамшутов" и "Раушанов" из "Чуркостана", то это все равно не будет мешать работать хорошему и толковому программисту. Если у человека руки из правильного места, то хлебушку он будет получать! Как правило, понапишут на "пыхе" года 3-4 и думают что они охрененные специалисты! :))) А писать под Linux , а под Android, а драйвера под OS X ? А новые системы ителектуальных домов, которые только только входят в обиход? Сейчас, как уже отметили выше, почти нет программистов которые могут написать не то что сортировку Хоара.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 а php уже обогнал по популярности vb?

@sys_dev да, драйвера сортировки Хоара под OS X -- это круто.

Comment: Sys_dev, а кто в вашем понимании хороший и толковый программист?
 Дело совершенно не в языке программирования а в подходе к выбору технологий и языка при решении той или иной задачи. И не важно для чего вы пишете для андроида или для линукс. Знание css html это совершенно не показатель крутости, на мой взгляд это должны в наше время знать все. Что касается приезжих джамшудов и раушанов из чурбанстана то могу вам сказать из своего опыт этим летом когда я потерял хороший заказ из за демпинга вот такого вот роушана. Он тупа уронил в два раза ценник на разработку проекта на джава.

Comment: @huffman: "Знание css html это совершенно не показатель крутости, на мой взгляд это должны в наше время знать все." Кто этот бред Вам сказал? Эти вещи нужны в строго очерченном круге задач. Я вот когда себе в команду беру человека, то ставлю ему на компьютер самый простейший вирус и если он не способен его вычистить руками, то гоню нахрен! Современный программер обязан знать что такое автозагрузка, что такое процесс и как его убить. Ну хотя бы уметь гуглить, если он вдруг на не знакомой ему ранее системе. Недавно спросил человека "Какое значение в ряду Фибоначи по номеру 40?". Не осилил!

Comment: Где вы берете такую траву? -)

Comment: @huffman по критериям @sys_dev я безнадёжен. Не могу вирус вычистить руками и не знаю числа Фибоначчи по номеру 40. Печально, но надежды больше нет.

Answer (score 1):

Предприятие не простое, но вполне реальное. Самые перспективные направления - enterprise и андроид. Стоит прорабатывать оба. На enterprise надо научиться делать сайты с базой данных, используя сервлеты, Spring и Hibernate. На андроиде - приложения, предоставляющие user interface  с серверами, внутри у которых опять же Spring и Hibernate, а язык запросов к ним - XML или Json. Жить с продажи приложений, действительно, вряд ли получится, но надо что-то написать в качестве портфолио и участвовать в тендерах на elance.com и odesk.com. Дальше видно будет - можно получить постоянную удаленную работу, можно свалить в Москву после приобретения опыта.

Answer (score 1):

Если удаленно/фриланс - то плюсую за android.
И вникнуть легче, и портфолио Вам никто не помешает набрать - напишите что-нибудь полезное, разместите в маркетах. Может, в Вас проснется Гений и удача улыбнется, тогда можете получать доход со своих приложений.

Comment: в андроид марките денег нет. более менее вменяемые деньги можно заработать разрабатывая под ios но без маркетинга и рекламы там тоже ловить нечего. Гениальность тут не причем.

Comment: ну нет, так нет..
знакомый написал игрульку, на c#, правда, под iOS+Android.
iOS денег не принес, игруха щас на спаде, но было и 500$ в месяц (с гугль маркета).
в одиночку. Имея в штате не одну подобную вещь, можно и жить.

Answer (score 0):

Может посмотреть в сторону "биржевые роботы"? Некоторые дяди, хорошо шарят в бизнесе, но плохо(скажем совсем не шарят) в программировании. Вот тут-то и вылезают на сцену Java, C# программеры. Может в эту сторону посмотреть?